# How to bind in WPF with values upstream in hierarchy?

Tags: wpf, binding, ivalueconverter

I have a list of items I wish to display in a `ListView/GridView`.  Each item is a class/object containing a format and array of bytes.  The format dictates how the bytes are to be displayed (hex or decimal).  I am using a converter to go back and forth between `TextBox.Text` and the byte array.

The converter needs the format and string/array.  I tried to use `IValueConverter` and pass the format as a `ConverterParameter`, but this didn't work since it is not a `DependencyProperty`.  I tried to use `IMultiValueConverter` but that didn't work because I do not get the format in `ConvertBack`.  I thought that if I could bind to the whole object (MyDataItem), then the converter would work fine.  However, I cannot figure out how to bind to that.  I tried a bunch of variations using `RelativeSource` and other properties, but couldn't figure it out.  Can someone help me with the binding?

If there is a better way to accomplish my task, feel free to suggest it.

```
public enum FormatEnum
{
    Decimal,
    Hex
}

public class MyDataItem
{
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }

    public FormatEnum Format { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<MyDataItem> DataItems = new ObservableCollection<MyDataItem>();
}
```

**XAML (with non-working binding)**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Format">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--ComboBox for the format-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Data">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path,
                                        Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=DataBytesConverter}, 
                                        ConverterParameter={Binding Format}}"/>                        
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Just a heads-up for future....you'll have a much better chance of getting questions answered if you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The more work you make people do to reproduce your exact problem, the less inclined they'll be to do so.

There are a couple of different ways of doing what you're trying to do, but the main problem is that the data you are binding to doesn't support [INPC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-inotifypropertychanged-in-wpf-mvvm/). I'll let you read up on that, but the problem is essentially that the left hand (your text display field) doesn't know what your right hand (the ComboBox) is doing. When the ComboBox changes the format it has to signal to anything that depends on it that the value has changed. That's where INPC comes in. You can implement it yourself if you like, and there are plenty of tutorials around the net showing how to do so, but it's much easier to just use an existing library like [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/), which is what I'll use here.

Before I go into detail, I should point out that your idea of using an IMultiValueConverter would in fact work, provided you passed in Data and Format as separate parameters so that it would update whenever either of them changes value. Many people will actually suggest solutions like this, but it's not the best way of doing what you're trying to achieve. Converters and behaviors are really just extensions of the view, which is fine when they expose parts of the view that you otherwise can't get to. But in your case the problem is that the data you are providing the view isn't in a format that your view can readily consume, and in a "proper" WPF application, it should be. Fixing your data beforehand is usually faster, a lot easier to debug when it goes wrong, and it opens up the possibility for things like unit testing. We already know that your MyDataItem class has to be either modified or replaced in order to support INPC, so that's a good place to do your values-to-text logic.

So to start with, create a view model for your model object that exposes the properties you want to pass to your view laye (i.e. "Format") and adds a new one for the text string you want to display (i.e. "DataText). We'll also create an update function to fill that string in, INPC support and a tiny bit of update logic:

```
public class MyDataItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private MyDataItem DataItem;

    public MyDataItemViewModel(MyDataItem dataItem)
    {
        this.DataItem = dataItem;
        UpdateDataText();
    }

    public FormatEnum Format
    {
        get { return this.DataItem.Format; }
        set
        {
            if (this.DataItem.Format != value)
            {
                this.DataItem.Format = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Format);
                UpdateDataText();
            }
        }
    }

    private string _DataText;
    public string DataText
    {
        get { return this._DataText; }
        set
        {
            if (this._DataText != value)
            {
                this._DataText = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.DataText);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateDataText()
    {
        switch (this.Format)
        {
            case FormatEnum.Decimal:
                this.DataText = String.Join(", ", this.DataItem.Data.Select(val => String.Format("{0:D}", val)));
                break;

            case FormatEnum.Hex:
                this.DataText = String.Join(", ", this.DataItem.Data.Select(val => String.Format("0x{0:X2}", val)));
                break;

            default:
                this.DataText = String.Empty;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Your "DataItems" collection needs to be public and accessible via a getter (something you didn't do in your original code), and it needs to be a collection of these view models instead:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyDataItemViewModel> DataItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MyDataItemViewModel>();
```

And now for each instance of MyDataItem you want to wrap it in an instance of MyDataItemViewModel:

```
this.DataItems.Add(new MyDataItemViewModel(new MyDataItem { Format = FormatEnum.Decimal, Data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 } }));
this.DataItems.Add(new MyDataItemViewModel(new MyDataItem { Format = FormatEnum.Decimal, Data = new byte[] { 4, 5, 6 } }));
```

Now your data is in a much better format. ObjectDataProvider provides a nice and convenient way to put all the values for a particular type of Enum in a single list that a ComboBox can bind to, so let's create one of those for your FormatEnum:

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<Window.Resources>

    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="FormatEnumValues" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type system:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:FormatEnum"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>

</Window.Resources>
```

And your ListView can now bind directly to all this data without any converters or behaviors or anything messy like that:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Format">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FormatEnumValues}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Format}" Width="100" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Header="Data">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataText}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MinWidth="100" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: In regards to using IMultiConverter, that does not work for the reason I stated.

I indeed have a public getter for DataItems, I thought that was implied.

I completely disagree with your assertion that a ViewModel should format the data for the View.  That is clearly not separating the data from the view, a goal of MVVM.  The ViewModel should be providing data and not be concerned with how it is displayed, that is up to the View.  After all, the a ViewModel could be attached to any View.  Converters are for exactly this situation: a View to display a ViewModel's data in its own way.

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking at your question again now, I thought you were doing a one-way conversion. The fact that you're using a TextBox implies you also want to convert the text back to the byte array, correct? Wasn't obvious from your question. If you insist on doing this in your view layer then you can do it using a behaviour instead.